# How can I create ui component with only two buttons (without table)

Tags: magento2

Can I create ui component for admin panel in my module only with two buttons? Click on each of them will process controller.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ui_component file at
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component add below code:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="import2" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import 2</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">route_name/controller/action</item>
        </item>
        <item name="import1" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import 1</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">route_name/controller/action</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but: PHP Fatal error:  Method Magento\\Ui\\TemplateEngine\\Xhtml\\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/mytest.su/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0, referer: https://mytest.su/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/b36f79d19eea53d6d6545f25a1182c52e3410d281149546fbe6534e2388ad73b/